# Broken icomoon icons in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sass, browser-cache, icomoon

There is a weird issue with icomoon icons in google chrome when devTools is opened. With random refreshes, all icons became characters like "ïƒ³", "ï€‡", "ïŠ�". After a refresh, icons back to normal. When the cache is disabled everything also works fine.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello have you found the solution ? In my case it happens also on Edge even more often